# Disable BLE extended advertising for linux

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hci

How can one disable extended features for BLE? Problem being that a node js ap using bleno runs great on a linux where the extended advertising isn't supported, but doesn't work on a linux where extended advertising is supported.

Can this feature somehow be turned off via some tool?

Comment: If a Bluetooth host only uses legacy advertising, that should still be compatible with controllers over hci. What error messages are you getting? Maybe bleno is just buggy. You can try my BLE library instead at https://github.com/Emill/node-ble-host to see if that one works better.

Comment: It's not buggy, the problem is that, I assume the kernel(?) sends a start extended advertising command when I do "hciconfig hci0 reset". This means that when I send a legacy advertising command afterwards, the error given is "Command Disallowed", because using legacy and extended commands interchangeably is forbidden.

Comment: You can use `sudo btmon` to check that theory. But yes, after a hci reset, if the host ever sends an extended advertisement command, it may not send a legacy one (until the next reset). If you use a custom bluetooth stack though, the kernel should not interfere.

Comment: Using the [Add Advertising Command](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt#n2617) from the MGMT API, choosing none of the secondary channel flags will result in legacy advertising.

Comment: So "hciconfig hci0 reset" didn't help. But this command did: sudo hcitool cmd 0x03 0x0003